# how do I use this variable found in a method outside of the method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use this var found inside of this method--also outside of the method. So  basically I want to bind its contents to a menu which is found in this array, but I can't seem to access it outside of this method.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
const imagePathArr = imagePathArr;

$('#content-frame').on('load', function() {
                        alert('iframe loaded.');
                        var vm=this;
                        let imagePathArr = [];
                    
                        $('#frame')[0].contentWindow.$('.inline').each(function(index) {
                            $(this).click();

                            const imageExtensions = ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif']; // Enter image extensions

                            $('#content-frame')[0].contentWindow.$('.inline').each(function() {
                                const fileName = $(this).children().text();
                                const fileExtension = fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

                                if (imageExtensions.includes(fileExtension)) { 
                                    imagePathArr.push($(this)[0].href);
                                   
                                
                                   
                                }
                            });
                        });

                        console.log(imagePathArr);
                        
                    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do `const imagePathArr = imagePathArr;`. You'd get the error "ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'imagePathArr' before initialization". Is that what your question is about?

Comment: if I rename it to const imagePathArrSomething = imagePathArr; can I use it that way?

Comment: it is    let imagePathArr = [];

Comment: What you are trying to do seems prone to race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the variable in the scope of the function called by `.ready()`, you need to declare the variable in a scope accessible to the function called by `.ready()` (either its scope or a scope it exists in).

The easiest way to do this is to declare the variable in `.ready()`, then assign to it in `.on()`. Here's a simplified example.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  /* Declare the variable in this function's scope */
  var imagePathArr;

  $('#content-frame').on('load', function() {

      /* Assign to the variable in this function's scope (the
         identifier is still accessible because the variable was
         declared in the parent scope) */
      imagePathArr = [];
  });

  /* The variable is still available as we're still in
     the scope from the declaration above */
  console.log(imagePathArr);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `let` ([let vs const](https://css-tricks.com/let-vs-const/)) to initialize the imagePathArr in global scope. Then you can modify the variable later, e.g. `imagePathArr = []` to reset the value later etc.

You can only create a variable once, for example:

```
const cannotChangeMe = "Im here forever";
let sample = "test";
var sample2 = "test2";
```

And if you want to reassign:

```
// const cannot be reassigned
sample = "im changed";
sample2 = "im changed2";
```

(Altough `var` is pretty much obsolete now, so better to use `const` or `let` nowadays)

```js
// sets the variables in global scope
let imagePathArr = [];
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#content-frame').on('load', function() {
                        alert('iframe loaded.');
                        var vm=this;
                        // "resets" the contents of the variable (creates an empty array)
                        imagePathArr = [];
                    
                        $('#frame')[0].contentWindow.$('.inline').each(function(index) {
                            $(this).click();

                            const imageExtensions = ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif']; // Enter image extensions

                            $('#content-frame')[0].contentWindow.$('.inline').each(function() {
                                const fileName = $(this).children().text();
                                const fileExtension = fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

                                if (imageExtensions.includes(fileExtension)) { 
                                    imagePathArr.push($(this)[0].href);
                                   
                                
                                   
                                }
                            });
                        });

                        console.log(imagePathArr);
                        
                    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

> let allows you to declare variables that are limited to the scope of a block statement, or expression on which it is used.

The variable imagePathArr is only accessible within the onLoad eventlistener. Depends on the usage, you could declare imagePathArr as a global variable like this:

```
var imagePathArr = [];
$(document).ready(function() {


$('#content-frame').on('load', function() {
                        alert('iframe loaded.');
                        var vm=this;
                        imagePathArr = [];
```

So you can access imagePathArr anywhere within the same JS file.